# How to have right arow behavior in a console

Tags: c, console, uart, bare-metal

I am trying to recreate a line editor in a bare metal environnement :
a chip receiving and sending data in an UART.

The UART is linked to a keyboard on input and a screen on output.

To simulate left arrow, i send the character <kbd>\b</kbd>.
I cannot find how to go right.

**About memory solution**

For now our system only send back the characters back to the UART to display it on the screen. There is no memory usage.
I thought of some solutions that need to memorize all the text inputed, for example the second part proposed in the @ikegami answer.

My question could then be : 
*The screen can understand <kbd>\b</kbd> as a backward move of the cursor. Is there a similar way to do it forward ? Or am i forced to compute it in the chip ?*

Comment: This is far too broad, you need to narrow down the question significantly. "Receive character" from what keyboard? An UART terminal? An actual keyboard? Something else? Is your question how to interface or use UART on some unknown hardware, debounce a switch, access a keyboard matrix... and so on. This is all unclear.

Comment: @Eric I guess I should be more careful when (blindly) following Wikipedia links, like that given for the `\b` code [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). ;(

Comment: What kind of terminal is it? Maybe [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) (e.g. `"\e[C"`) will work

Comment: @ikegami - removed comment.

Comment: send a space, a VT 0x0B, a TAB 0x09... Or any non-printing character and on the receiving side act accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` was probably originally for printers. One could use it to print two characters on top of each other (e.g. `A` and `_` to create an underlined `A`, or `A` and `A` to create a bold `A`).

To move forward on a printer, one can simply print a space. Of course, on a terminal, that usually erases the existing character.

Enter ANSI escape sequences. Maybe [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) will work for you. For example, printing `"\e[C"` will move the cursor forward one (up to the limits of the terminal) on some terminals.

```
$ perl -e'
   print "abcd";
   print "\e[D\e[D\e[D";  # Go back
   print "e";             # Edit
   print "\e[C\e[C";      # Move forward
   print "f";             # Add more to the end
   print "\e[C";          # Move forward
   print "g\n";           # Add more to the end
'
aecdf g
```

(The choice of language isn't relevant. It's just more compact to demo using Perl.)

Alternatively, print a space. If that would overwrite a character you don't want overwritten, remember what that character is and print that character instead of a space.

```
$ perl -e'
   print "abcd";
   print "\b\b\b";        # Go back
   print "e";             # Edit
   print "cd";            # Move forward
   print "f";             # Add more to the end
   print " ";             # Move forward
   print "g\n";
'
aecdf g
```

Comment: Thanks i will try; I actually did thought about reprinting the last character, but that forces me to keep in memory all text typed, that i don't do for now.

Comment: Yup, but it's what you're going to have to do unless your chip supports something like ANSI escape sequences.